# Best way to get validate user in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am somewhat in the dark about how to approach this problem but hopefully your guys' input will help me.

I am trying to only allow Users of my "homepage/calendar" website to view content only they create. In my mind to do this I would need to go into each Create, Add, Remove, and Update function and get the current userID using:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

I would then compare this UserID with a UserID that I stored in the table when the function is run.

here is what my tables would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] (
    [LoginProvider] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]        NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LoginProvider] ASC, [ProviderKey] ASC, [UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);



    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events] (
    [EventID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Subject]     NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (300) NULL,
    [Start]       DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [End]         DATETIME       NULL,
    [ThemeColor]  NVARCHAR (10)  NULL,
    [IsFullDay]   BIT            NOT NULL,
    [UserId]        NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Event__7944C8701D5AFFC5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Links] (
    [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Link] VARCHAR (1000) NULL,
    [UserId]        NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__tmp_ms_x__3214EC07BE58FD26] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I am hoping there is a simpler or more elegant solution. I will eventually be turning this project in to a bootcamp and showing employers.

Here is my home controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;



namespace HomePageCalendar.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private MyDatabaseEntities _context;

        public HomeController()
        {
            _context = new MyDatabaseEntities();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        public ActionResult New()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Links home)
        {
            _context.Links.Add(home);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "home");
        }
        public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
        {
            var Link = from l in _context.Links
                       select l;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                Link = Link.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            var Name = _context.Links.ToList();
            return View(Link);

        }

        public ActionResult Remove()
        {
            ViewBag.title = "Remove Links";
            ViewBag.homes = _context.Links.ToList();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Remove(int[] cheeseIds)
        {
            foreach (int cheeseId in cheeseIds)
            {
                Links theCheese = _context.Links.Single(c => c.Id == cheeseId);
                _context.Links.Remove(theCheese);
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Redirect("/");
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's pretty much how you'd do it.  When a user requests to view or modify data, you check if that current user is allowed to view or modify that data.  If they are, allow it.  If they're not, return an error or in some way provide a failure response.  There's lots of ways to "check if they're allowed", depending on your business logic and how you want to handle failed checks.

Comment: @David Thanks for the reply. I updated the OP with my home controller. So basically you are saying in each function I should verify the user is the current one?

Comment: There are a variety of ways you could do it.  For example, when the user requests a record by its ID, you could fetch that record by that ID *and* by the UserID.  If no match is found, treat it as a 404.  Or perhaps fetch the record by only the ID and then write an `if` to see if the record's UserID matches the current user.  If it doesn't, return a permission denied error.  Basically, how you implement it depends on how you want the system to behave.